# Run Jython code from java class

Tags: java, jython

I am working on executable jar file that will run jython file to get some result.
I tried calling jython file through this technique.

Run `.bat` file from java class and that `.bat` file will call `Jython` file.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = rt.exec(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c", "D:\\calljython.bat " + parameters + "" });
```

After jython file runs I read output through `InputStream` and get results.
This technique works file when run from eclipse but fails when executable jar is created and run.

Another thing I use is `PythonInterpreter` but also face problems in this case.

**What I want to do is:**

Run Jython code from java along with parameters to be used in Jython file and get result.

Comment: What is the failure? Do you get any stacktrace?

Comment: From executable jar I could not get any stacktrace. It takes some input as per logic and then nothing happens.

Comment: My Advise is to put either log or print statements and find what is really happening so that it will be easier. Print the command to be executed. Process.waitFor() return code etc.

Comment: How can I add logs in executable jar file? I tried log4j but it did not work.

Comment: Then put System.out.println(). You can put log4j in executable jars. You would just need to specify the log4j either inside of MANIFEST.MF's classpath element or in system classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try debugging code and make sure that bat file or jython are being called and returning results. bat file should places along-with jar file you are executing (same hierarchy).

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = rt.exec(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c", "calljython.bat " + parameters + "" });
```